# Phonegap basics - designing ui for iphone and android

Tags: user-interface, plugins, cordova

I'm developing an application both for Iphone and Andriod using Phonegap.

I came up with all kinds of plugins JQuery, JQTouch and more,

What is the recommended way of doing this?
Meaning-designing a generic UI (tabbars, tables, navigation bars etc') for both Iphone,Android that will "feel" native?

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application to look as native as possible I'd try [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/).

The documentation is brilliant and all of elements look native to the iPhone. It's also incredibly easy and quick to build up your UI as all of the design and colour scheme has already been done.

I've used this in an Android application that I've made and I've so far received very positive reviews.

You may also want to look out for [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/kendo-ui-mobile.aspx) which is out this month! Again, very similar to what jQuery mobile is about with a few exceptions. It has great support for graphs and data, and promotes native Android look and feel.

Comment: Forget jQueyr mobile.. check this out  .. http://pkula.blogspot.com/2011/12/kendo-ui-mobile-and-phonegap-leaked.html

Answer (score 1):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) has just released version 2 and it is a good JS toolkit as well.

Comment: Hi Simon,Is the Sencha touch limited only to Chrome and Safari? if so what will be the result of a user without any of the following browsers operating the application?

Answer (score 1):

I feel I have to put my hat in the ring for jQTouch. Although the version downloadable from their site is a bit oldish, if you get it from GitHub it is currently maintained and works well on both iOS and Android. https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch

Also, if you want the fixed headers or footers with scrollable elements in-between, DataZombie's fork of jQTouch includes iScroll which does a great job of this. https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch

I am also in the process of developing a theme for jQTouch that will allow apps on Android to feel quite a bit more "native" than the other js kits as they all seem to have a very iOS-cenrtic navigation style (e.g.: back buttons on toolbars instead of relying on the hardware back button, etc). Even if you don't want to wait for my theme, making your own is pretty easy on jQTouch. I would not call myself a designer and I managed. ;)

Feel free to choose one of the other answers, but keep jQTouch in mind. I tried and tried other JavaScript frameworks and it was the only one that made it possible to look good on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile works awesomely.. and with the theme roller coming soon it will be pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Mobile UI  - Pre release rip.. I have a working Eclispe project here.. markup is identical to jQuery mobile.. but this is faster, nice native looking apps. [Take a look](http://pkula.blogspot.com/2011/12/kendo-ui-mobile-and-phonegap-leaked.html)